# C++: cannot find include file "functions.h" on NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, header-files

got some problem here. Me and my fellow student are doing homeworks for our programming course. I´m using NetBeans on Windows 10. Its the IDE 8.0.2 version. And some how i got the error:

`Cannot find include file "functions.h"`

`#include "functions.h"`

Well the function.h file is missing in folder, too. It´s maybe totally stupid, but i tried to copy the functions.h file from my course partner and past it in my folder. Doesn´t really worked.

Comment: So the file's not in your folder and you wonder why `#include "functions.h"` errs? That's peculiar. And I don't understand your question.

Comment: This is why a first programming class is hard.  You need to put that file in the _correct_ folder for this to work, and without knowing how your environment is setup, the we don't know what the _correct_ folder is.  In this case (`#include "..."`) it needs to be _in the same directory_ as the file that has the `#include` statement.

Comment: what i don´t understand is, my fellow didn´t add anyhting or setup anything different than me. But when he wrote #include "functions.h", he didn´t have that problem. I know the .h file should be in the same folder. But i can´t find it anywhere. And actually i normaly don´t use NetBeans as IDE. It´s just my professor who said: "Guys use NetBeans or get out of my course." Since then i only got problems, i never had with VS.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the files tab would look with the simplest way to add functions.h so it will compile. Take a look at your files tab and see if the .cpp or .h is in the wrong directory. Your paste putting it in the wrong directory would be a simple explanation. I have noticed that in one place you have functions.h and in another you mention function.h (On ends with `s` and the other does not. ) A simple typo like that would be an easy way to get this kind of error.

[image: C++ setup]

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i see, i mistyped the 2nd time in my first post. But i checked again my code.It´s till the same, no mistyping. Is there a option to manually add the functions.h file? I even tried to open a new project. Wrote all headers before copying the rest of the code.

[screenshot missing functions.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJLAk.jpg)